# Ruby, How to generate JSON format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I need to send an input in the below format to an API, I'm running into problems producing the desired format which is below.

> { "application" :
>   "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"genesis__Applications__c\"},\"genesis__Days_Convention__c\":\"ACTUAL/ACTUAL\",  \"RecordTypeID\":\"012260000004RHF\",
>   \"genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c\":\"Flat\",
>   \"genesis__Interest_Rate__c\":10.0000,
>   \"genesis__Loan_Amount__c\":22120.00,
>   \"Application_Completed__c\":false,
>   \"genesis__Payment_Frequency__c\":\"WEEKLY\",
>   \"genesis__Product_Type__c\":\"LOAN\",       \"genesis__Term__c\":24, 
>   \"genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c\":2,
>   \"genesis__Balloon_Payment__c\":100.00}", "relatedObjects" :   "{
>   \"genesis__Account__c\" :       {\"attributes\":
>   {\"type\":\"Account\"},       \"Name\":\"LONDON METALS HOLDINGS
>   LIMITED\" },     \"Loan_Product_Purpose__c\" :      {\"attributes\":
>   {\"type\":\"Loan_Product_Purpose__c\"},       \"Name\":\"Equipment
>   Purchase\" }}" }

API is accepting above format as input.

Input specifications as shown.
[image]

We tried JSON builder that did not help instead producing the below format
which is not valid for API.

> "\"{:attributes:{:type:\\"genesis__Applications__c\\"},
>   :genesis__Days_Convention__c:\\"ACTUAL/ACTUAL\\",
>   :RecordTypeID:\\"012260000004RHF\\",
>   :genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c:\\"Flat\\",
>   :genesis__Interest_Rate__c:10.0, :genesis__Loan_Amount__c:22120.0,
>   :Application_Completed__c:false,
>   :genesis__Payment_Frequency__c:\\"WEEKLY\\",
>   :genesis__Product_Type__c:\\"LOAN\\", :genesis__Term__c:24,
>   :genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c:2,
>   :genesis__Balloon_Payment__c:100.0}\""

edit1: Input Hash object

> {:application=>   {:attributes=>{:type=>"genesis__Applications__c"},
>   :genesis__Days_Convention__c=>"ACTUAL/ACTUAL",
>   :RecordTypeID=>"012260000004RHF",
>   :genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c=>"Flat",
>   :genesis__Interest_Rate__c=>10.0,
>   :genesis__Loan_Amount__c=>22120.0,
>   :Application_Completed__c=>false,
>   :genesis__Payment_Frequency__c=>"WEEKLY",
>   :genesis__Product_Type__c=>"LOAN",    :genesis__Term__c=>24,
>   :genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c=>2,
>   :genesis__Balloon_Payment__c=>100.0},  :relatedObjects=>
>   {:genesis__Account__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Account"},
>   :Name=>"LONDON METALS HOLDINGS LIMITED"},
>   :Loan_Product_Purpose__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Loan_Product_Purpose__c"}, :Name=>"Equipment Purchase"}}}

Comment: Most of the time a simple `JSON.dump(hash)` should work. How do you build the hash and how to you try to generate JSON out of the hash?

Comment: @spickermann Q updated.

Comment: Build out a [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org) specification for what you need because I can't see what's wrong here at a glance. `JSON.dump` does a great job 99% of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your code used toward solving this. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, and SO isn't a "write code for me" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you using JSON? It should work just fine

```
require 'json'

h = {:application=> 
{:attributes=>{:type=>"genesis__Applications__c"},
             :genesis__Days_Convention__c=>"ACTUAL/ACTUAL",
             :RecordTypeID=>"012260000004RHF",
             :genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c=>"Flat",
             :genesis__Interest_Rate__c=>10.0,
             :genesis__Loan_Amount__c=>22120.0,
             :Application_Completed__c=>false,
             :genesis__Payment_Frequency__c=>"WEEKLY",
             :genesis__Product_Type__c=>"LOAN", :genesis__Term__c=>24,
             :genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c=>2,
             :genesis__Balloon_Payment__c=>100.0}, :relatedObjects=>
    {:genesis__Account__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Account"}, :Name=>"LONDON METALS HOLDINGS LIMITED"},
:Loan_Product_Purpose__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Loan_Product_Purpose__c"}, :Name=>"Equipment Purchase"}}}


puts h.to_json
```

prints:

```
 {"application":{"attributes":{"type":"genesis__Applications__c"},"genesis__Days_Convention__c":"ACTUAL/ACTUAL","RecordTypeID":"012260000004RHF","genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c":"Flat","genesis__Interest_Rate__c":10.0,"genesis__Loan_Amount__c":22120.0,"Application_Completed__c":false,"genesis__Payment_Frequency__c":"WEEKLY","genesis__Product_Type__c":"LOAN","genesis__Term__c":24,"genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c":2,"genesis__Balloon_Payment__c":100.0},"relatedObjects":{"genesis__Account__c":{"attributes":{"type":"Account"},"Name":"LONDON METALS HOLDINGS LIMITED"},"Loan_Product_Purpose__c":{"attributes":{"type":"Loan_Product_Purpose__c"},"Name":"Equipment Purchase"}}}
```

---

Ok, now I see the value of `application` and `relatedObjects` are strings (with json content). So try this instead:

```
require 'json'


application = {:attributes=>{:type=>"genesis__Applications__c"},
           :genesis__Days_Convention__c=>"ACTUAL/ACTUAL",
           :RecordTypeID=>"012260000004RHF",
           :genesis__Interest_Calculation_Method__c=>"Flat",
           :genesis__Interest_Rate__c=>10.0,
           :genesis__Loan_Amount__c=>22120.0,
           :Application_Completed__c=>false,
           :genesis__Payment_Frequency__c=>"WEEKLY",
           :genesis__Product_Type__c=>"LOAN", :genesis__Term__c=>24,
           :genesis__Interest_Only_Period__c=>2,
           :genesis__Balloon_Payment__c=>100.0}

relatedObjects = {:genesis__Account__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Account"}, :Name=>"LONDON METALS HOLDINGS LIMITED"},
              :Loan_Product_Purpose__c=>{:attributes=>{:type=>"Loan_Product_Purpose__c"}, :Name=>"Equipment Purchase"}}

h = {:application=> application.to_json,
     :relatedObjects=> relatedObjects.to_json}


puts h.to_json
```